# module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

```
self.summaries_train = tf.summary.merge(self.summaries_train)
```

Error: module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'merge'

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

it has been depreciated in TensorBoard 2.6 and above. instead, use this:

```
self.summaries_train = tf.summary.merge_all(scope='train')
```